# R states column doesn't exist, but I can clearly see it. Returns Error in 'select()'

Tags: r, sorting, select, dplyr, mutate

I am in the beginning of learning how to use R, and I am assuming this is an issue with how I am formatting my code but I have tried every way I have looked up and know how.

When looking at my spotify dataset, I wanted to mutate a column, creating one that is titled "is_not_broke" for users that have been identified (by utilizing grepl) to have the words 'paid subscription' in the column 'spotify_subscription_plan'.  my code looks like this.

```
spot_data %>%
select(Gender:'spotify_listening_device', 'premium_sub_willingness', 'spotify_subcription_plan') %>%
mutate(is_not_broke = grepl('paid subscrition', 'spotify_subcription_plan'))
```

but I get this error

```
Error in `select()`:
Can't subset columns that don't exist.
Column `spotify_subcription_plan` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
rlang::last_trace()
> > <error/vctrs_error_subscript_oob>
Error in `select()`:
Can't subset columns that don't exist.
Column `spotify_subcription_plan` doesn't exist.
> > ---
Backtrace:
> >     ▆
1. ├─... %>% ...
2. ├─dplyr::mutate(., is_not_broke = grepl("paid subscrition", "spotify_subcription_plan"))
3. ├─dplyr::select(...)
4. └─dplyr:::select.data.frame(...)
```

my dataframe shows this column

[image]

I have tried rewording spotify_subscription_plan with and without quotes but still get the same error.

Comment: Don't use quotes when using variable names within `select()`.

Comment: Double check the spelling of the column in your code

Comment: Can't quote columns in a `mutate()` and `select()` and the spaces in the header will through off R also

Comment: You have used single quotes:  `'` but you want backticks `\`` or nothing.  You have also misspelled the column name (you omitted the p in subscri**p**tion in one, and the second s in another).

Comment: Please show us the output of `names(spot_data)` in your question ...

Comment: @paulstaffordallen thank you! I applied your recommendations and my code works now.

Answer (score 0):

> You have used single quotes: ' but you want backticks ` or nothing. You have also misspelled the column name (you omitted the p in subscription in one, and the second s in another). [Credit: Paul Stafford Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76629876/r-states-column-doesnt-exist-but-i-can-clearly-see-it-returns-error-in-selec#comment135105679_76629876)